# Using Angular element ID to addClass but wont add the class after page renders

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I need help with some code with Angular.  I'm pretty new to this (first post) so I'll try to explain the best I can.  In short i want to add a class to a element ID when an email is an empty string.  The contacts has an array of emails.

The main problem is that it seems that after the page renders the information the Element ID did not have the class added like i thought it would.

If i go into console on google chrome and do angular.element('id').addClass('class') it would works and does add the class to the element but when i put it on this function it does not show after the page renders.

Any help would be great!  Thank you.

For example:

```
 $scope.ContactResults.forEach(function (item, index) {
        item.resourceID = index;
        if (item.email == '') {
            angular.element('#Contacts_email_externalLink-' + index).addClass('hide-icon');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Which technology is rendering your views?

Comment: Using angular 1.6 with breeze.  The section i'm working on is being render by a meta-driven-table.  All the pages load properly with the proper data  but it just does not add the class to trigger some other features.    I have very little to no angular experience and pretty new to coding in general started in June.  

Code that is being edit is in the controller.js.

Comment: Does AngularJS render your views?

Comment: Yes i belive so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `ng-class` combined with `$scope` params for stuff like this. Don't manipulate the DOM with `angular.element()` directly:

#### View

```
<a href="mailto:who@ever.knows" 
   ng-class="{ 'hide-icon' : hideIcon }">Email external link</a>
```

#### Application logic:

```
$scope.hideIcon = false;
$scope.ContactResults.forEach(function (item, index) {
    item.resourceID = index;
    if (item.email.length === 0) {
       $scope.hideIcon = true;
    } else {
       $scope.hideIcon = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: I'll try to give this a go.   The ng-class already has that hide-icon: hideIcon when i checked, just didn't know what to do with it.  Thx lin!!!

Answer (score 0):

What if instead of ids elements. use the ng-class

```
<form>
    <div ng-repeat="item in ContactResults">
       <input type="email" ng-model="item.email"> 
       <div id="Contacts_email_externalLink-{{$index}}" 
            class="some-class" 
            ng-class="{true:'hide-icon', false:''}[item.email.length > 0]">
       </div>
</form>
```